# How to use $set in Nuxt store mutations?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm trying to modify the value of a Vuex store object key, but I'm getting errors with the three following ways:

```
export const mutations = {
  USER_UPDATE(state, payload) {
    this.$set(state.user, 'name', payload.name), // test 1
    // vm.$set(state.user, 'name', payload.name), // test 2
    // Vue.$set(state.user, 'name', payload.name)}, // test 3
  }
}
```

With `this.` and `vm.`, I get **ReferenceError: vm is not defined**

With `Vue.` and `import Vue from 'vue'` at the top of my `store/index.js` file, I get **TypeError: vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.default.$set is not a function**

What's the correct way to use `$set` with Nuxt store `mutations` ?

Comment: `Vue.$set` should be [`Vue.set`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Comment: do you really need it?

Comment: @Ifaruki in this particular example, it's not necessary indeed, but for nested object, it is → [Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

Comment: @tony19 Thanks, it works fine but it needs `import Vue from 'vue'` at the top of store store file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fixed it using this syntax:

```
export const mutations = {
  USER_UPDATE(state, payload) {
    this._vm.$set(state.user, 'name', payload.name);
  }
}
```